# tensorflow tfrecord storage for large datasets

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the "proper" method of storage for large datasets for tensorflow ingestion. The documentation seems relatively clear that no matter what, tfrecord files are preferred. Large is a subjective measure, but the examples below are randomly generated regression datasets from sklearn.datasets.make_regression() of 10,000 rows and between 1 and 5,000 features, all float64.

I've experimented with two different methods of writing tfrecord files with dramatically different performance.

For numpy arrays, `X`, `y` (X.shape=(10000, n_features), y.shape=(10000,)

### `tf.train.Example` with per-feature `tf.train.Features`

I construct a tf.train.Example in the way that tensorflow developers seem to prefer, at least judging by tensorflow example code at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py.

For each observation or row in `X`, I create a dictionary keyed with feature names (f_0, f_1, ...) whose values are `tf.train.Feature` objects with the feature's observation data as a single element of its float_list.

```
def _feature_dict_from_row(row):
    """
    Take row of length n+1 from 2-D ndarray and convert it to a dictionary of
    float features:

      {
        'f_0': row[0],
        'f_1': row[1],
        ...
        'f_n': row[n]
      }
    """
    def _float64_feature(feature):
        return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[feature]))

    features = { "f_{:d}".format(i): _float64_feature(value) for i, value in enumerate(row) }
    return features

def write_regression_data_to_tfrecord(X, y, filename):
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('{:s}'.format(filename)) as tfwriter:
        for row_index in range(X.shape[0]):
            features = _feature_dict_from_row(X[row_index])
            features['label'] = y[row_index]

            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
            tfwriter.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

### `tf.train.Example` with one large `tf.train.Feature` containing all features

I construct a dictionary with one feature (really two counting the label) whose value is a `tf.train.Feature` with the entire feature row in as its float_list

```
def write_regression_data_to_tfrecord(X, y, filename, store_by_rows=True):
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('{:s}'.format(filename)) as tfwriter:
        for row_index in range(X.shape[0]):
            features = { 'f_0': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=X[row_index])) }
            features['label'] = y[row_index]

            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
            tfwriter.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

As the number of features in the dataset grows, the second option gets considerably faster than the first, as shown in the following graph. *Note the log scale*

**10,000 rows:**

[image: graph]

It makes intuitive sense to me that creating 5,000 `tf.train.Feature` objects is significantly slower than creating one object with a float_list of 5,000 elements, but it's not clear that this is the "intended" method for feeding large numbers of features into a tensorflow model.

Is there something inherently wrong with doing this the faster way?

Comment: Does your graph show record _creation_ time? What about the impact of the record architecture on _training_ time? Aren't we more interested in the later?

Comment: It's a good question, but I haven't even gotten to the training time yet. In reality, the design matrices I'm working with are on the order of 1B x 100K and they change quite a bit, so if method A is the "right" way, it will be so prohibitively expensive to write the data that I'll have to find another method.

Comment: Hi @davidr, I'd be curious if you came up with anything.